# almacenar lista de una columna de un archivo csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Tengo un problema al crear listas con información de un archivo csv. Lo que quiero es almacenar una lista por cada 'columna' del archivo. Todo lo que he ido intentando me ha llevado a generar listas de cada una de las 'filas', no obstante lo que quiero no es eso. Este es lo que he conseguido:

```
import csv


with open('02_CSV_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as my_csv_file:
    reader=csv.reader(my_csv_file,delimiter=',')

    lista1=[]
    for column in reader:
        lista1.append(column[0])
print(lista1)
```

¡Y lo he conseguido!
No obstante, al volver a crear otra lista con la segunda columna y usando el mismo proceso pero distinto índice, me lanza una lista vacía. Si en ese mismo código que adjunto, cambio el índice, me aparece una lista con la columna correspondiente. Es como si no pudiera hacerlo varias veces. Sólo una vez.

Llevo varias horas y seguramente la solución esté claro pero no consigo verlo. Uso python 3.x sin pandas.

Gracias y saludos

Comment: esto es una fila `'hola','hola2'` donde el primer elemento corresponde a la primera columna, si tu quieres crear columnas tendras que escribir de forma vertical y no horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
with open('quinta.csv', 'r', newline='') as my_csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file, delimiter=',')
    lista = []
    for linea in reader:
        for columna in range(len(linea)):
            if columna >= len(lista):
                lista.append([])
            lista[columna].append(linea[columna])
```

El problema demanda crear una lista de lista, donde cada sublista corresponde al contenido de una columna. Partimos con una lista vacía, ya que no sabemos cuantas columnas tiene el .csv, e incluso puede ser un .csv con número variable de columnas:

```
lista = []
```

Luego tenemos que leer línea a línea del .csv.

```
for linea in reader:
```

Cada línea es una lista de valores que recorremos con un `for` variando el índice a examinar:

```
for columna in range(len(linea)):
    if columna >= len(lista):
        lista.append([])
    lista[columna].append(linea[columna])
```

En cada iteración revisamos si `lista` ya tiene una sublista para la columna actual. Si no, incorporamos una sublista vacía.

El último paso es tomar el elemento en la posición `columna` y agregarlo a la sublista en el índice `columna` de `lista`.

#### Demo

*quinta.csv*

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10
1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.
11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

*código*

```
import csv

with open('quinta.csv', 'r', newline='') as my_csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_csv_file, delimiter=',')
    lista = []
    for linea in reader:
        for columna in range(len(linea)):
            if columna >= len(lista):
                lista.append([])
            lista[columna].append(linea[columna])

    for col in lista:
        print(col)
```

produce:

```
['1', '10', '-1', '1.', '11', '1']
['2', '20', '-2', '2.', '21', '2']
['3', '30', '-3', '3.', '31', '3']
['4', '40', '-4', '4.', '41', '4']
['5', '50', '-5', '5.', '51', '5']
['6', '60', '-6', '6.', '61', '6']
['7', '70', '-7', '7.', '71', '7']
['8', '80', '-8', '8.', '81', '8']
['9', '90', '-9', '9.', '91', '9']
['10', '100', '-10', '10.', '101', '10']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias!! Le eché un vistazo esta mañana y encontré una solución parecida. Ayer no tuve mi día T-T.